# Bootstrap 2 accordion menu collapse

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 2 to build a wordpress theme with a collapsable menu, and everything works fine, however the open item doesn't close when I click a new item in the menu. any idea?

The php can be disregarded :) Thanks.

PS: When I tested with pure html it worked just fine

```
<div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading"><a href="#<?=$catItem->slug;?>" class="accordion-toggle show-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#<?=$generalActiveMenu;?>" id="<?=$catItem->term_id;?>"><?=$catItem->name;?></a></div>
    <div id="<?=$catItem->slug;?>" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <div id="<?=$generalActiveMenu;?>1" class="accordion">
                <?  $subCategory = new $Category();
                    $subCategory->getCategoryList($catItem->term_id); /* get sub category of each product */
                    foreach($subCategory->catList as $key => $subCatItem) {
                        ?><div class="accordion-group">
                            <div class="accordion-heading">
                                <a href="#<?=$subCatItem->slug;?>" class="accordion-toggle show-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#<?=$generalActiveMenu;?>1"  id="<?=$subCatItem->term_id;?>"><?=$subCatItem->name;?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="<?=$subCatItem->slug;?>" class="accordion-body collapse">
                                <? if(get_posts('category_name='.$subCatItem->slug)) {
                                    ?><div class="accordion-inner">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
                                            <? $Post->postCat = $subCatItem->term_id; 
                                            $Post->getPostList(); 
                                            foreach ($Post->postList as $key => $postItem) {
                                                ?><li id="<?=$postItem->post_name;?>"><a href="<?=$postItem->post_name;?>"><?=$postItem->post_title;?></a></li><?
                                            } ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div><?
                                } ?>                                            
                            </div>
                        </div><?
                    }
                ?>                          
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think the only way to try this out is to see a demo so that we can debug it.

Comment: I can not provide a demo, however I just want the previous item to close when I click a new one...

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but you could try:

```
 $('#myAccordianTab').collapse({
   toggle: true
 })
```

Take a look at this link for more info:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

This should help you build up correctly and and explains the toggle(or collapsing) function

Comment: That doesn't work. And I've looked on those documents for the past 2 days. I can't seem to find the bug.